# Set Up a Server

Tags: networking

we want to set up a server in our office and we face some problems.
We have a network with 9 computers all in Windows.
We would like to change our server from Windows Server to Ubuntu Desktop (or Server if this is more suitable).
Is that possible (only server with ubuntu and the rest with windows)?
Could we get some support from you (some person to talk to and possible to visit us in our office) on this issue?
Thank you for your actions.
Sincerely.

Comment: For most scenarios, yes. Linux server can easily replace Windows server as a file server using Samba, mail server , web server, database server, etc. But if your company relies on some proprietary software and you need to run a license server, for example, you will still need a server for that.
But what are those problems you're facing that you hope to solve by migrating to Linux?

Comment: And if you ask for personal assistance in your office, you should probably give some hints, where that might be.

Comment: Isn't this what Cannonical does? Give support to companies?

Comment: I also just wanted to recommend to talk to Canonical about business use of Ubuntu. http://www.canonical.com/

Comment: Please provide more info on what your Windows server does now, so that we could tell if you might run those services with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set up a server on Ubuntu, and serve information to your office or to the whole world. What would you want the server to serve? Do your business programs have a Linux version or do you just want a file or web server? 
As for the second part, having your approximate geographical location would be useful.

Comment: More information on the types of packages you need to install is [in these question and answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49299/can-i-use-a-desktop-as-a-network-server?rq=1)